# Почта на PHP

Tags: php

1. `$m->Attach( $file,"", "image/gif" );` отправляет исключительно файлы типа gif, сменить на jpeg или что-то другое работать не будет,
2. письмо не отправится пока файл не загрузишь, а хотелось бы не зависимо загружен файл или нет, а письмо отправлялось.

-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Simple Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?PHP
    include "libmail.php";

        // Вот тут я дописываю код(начало)
        $email = $_POST['email']; // Email
        $subject = $_POST['subject']; // Тема письма
        $text = $_POST['text']; // Текст письма
        $send = $_POST['send']; // Кнопка "Отправить"
        $file= $_POST['file'];
        // Вот тут я дописываю код(конец)

        if(isset($send)) // Если нажата кнопка "Отправить"
    {   
        $m = new Mail("utf-8"); // начинаем
        $m->From( "мое мыло" ); // от кого отправляется почта
        $m->To( $email ); // кому адресованно
        $m->Subject( $subject );
        $m->Body( $text );    
        $m->Cc( "мыло получателя"); // копия письма отправится по этому адресу
        $m->Bcc( "мыло получателя"); // скрытая копия отправится по этому адресу
        $m->Priority(3) ;    // приоритет письма
        $m->Attach( $file,"", "image/gif" ) ;
        $m->smtp_on( "smtp.mail.ru", "мое мыло", "пасс от мыла" ) ; // если указана эта команда, отправка пойдет через SMTP
        $m->Send();    // а теперь пошла отправка
        $m->Receipt();
        echo "Показывает исходный текст письма:<br><pre>", $m->Get(), "</pre>";
        }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="email">eMail:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subject">тема:</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="30" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="text">текс:</label>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="20" name="text" id="text"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="text">отправить файл:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="отправить" />
    </p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($_POST['file'])){
    $m->Attach($_POST['file'], "", "image/gif") ;
}
```

Но лучше бы еще проверить правильность загрузки файла и путь до него. По памяти не вспомню что там приходит при загрузке. Гугл.

**Добавлено из комментария.**

Выглядят так, как будто им строка передается, поэтому и вопрос был.

Мои действия: `Гугл -> libmail.php -> 1й результат ссылка на http://lwest.free.fr/doc/php/lib/index.php3?page=mail&lang=en`

Там описание работы класса с вложениями:

```
$mail->Attach( "logo.gif", "image/gif" );
$mail->Attach( 'C:/Mes Documents/resume.doc', "application/x-msword", "attachment" );
```

Понятно, что в вашем скрипте неправильно?

Comment: да все правильно, все остальные файлы всете с GIF лежат в одной папке только GIF отправляет а другие нет!

Comment: это условие тоже не работает, теперь если я прикреплю файл оно не отправляет

Comment: Глупый вопрос конечно, но чем заполнены методы From, Cc и Bcc?

Может из-за указанного типа image/gif не передает другие файлы?

Comment: а чем они должны быть заполнены??? и это второй вопрос, первый как отправлять по желанию есть файл или нет, условие ваше работает уже только если файла нет! если есть не отправляет

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: понятно что там описаны файлы gif, это можно думаю там исправить, но как бы с файлами, без него письмо не идет, можно разве что строку закоментировать но это не выход